# How to output SQL Database in a specific format based on the ROWID

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, database

What I'm trying to attempt is to select information from a database and group them by the ROWID and output them.

My Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT_RECORDS (
 RECORDS_ROWID number(3) not null,
 RECORDS_LISTCOLUMNID number (3) not null,
 RECORDS_RECORDVALUE varchar2 (25)
);
```

Sample Data

```
RECORDS_ROWID RECORDS_LISTCOLUMNID  RECORDS_RECORDVALUE   

    1                    1          First Row                    
    1                    2          First Row Description    
    1                    3          First Row Date        
    2                    1          Second Row                      
    2                    2          Second Row Description          
    2                    3          Second Row Date  
    3                    1          Third Row  
    3                    2          Third Row Description   
    3                    3          Third Row Date
```

How I want it to be displayed

```
 - First Row    - First Row Description   - First Row Data
 - Second Row   - Second Row Description  - Second Row Date
 - Third Row    - Third Row Description   - Third Row Date
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If using Oracle 11 then use LISTAGG()... GROUP BY RECORDS_LISTCOLUMNID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little maybe quicker solution than AjV

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02e21/17)**

```
SELECT 
 MAX(CASE WHEN RECORDS_LISTCOLUMNID = 1
       THEN RECORDS_RECORDVALUE
       ELSE '' END)  AS col1,
 MAX(CASE WHEN RECORDS_LISTCOLUMNID = 2
       THEN RECORDS_RECORDVALUE
       ELSE '' END) AS col2,
 MAX(CASE WHEN RECORDS_LISTCOLUMNID = 3
       THEN RECORDS_RECORDVALUE
       ELSE '' END) AS col3
FROM PROJECT_RECORDS
GROUP BY RECORDS_ROWID
```

Result:

```
|       COL1 |                   COL2 |            COL3 |
|------------|------------------------|-----------------|
|  First Row |  First Row Description |  First Row Date |
| Second Row | Second Row Description | Second Row Date |
|  Third Row |  Third Row Description |  Third Row Date |
```

Comment: This code doesn't output in the same manner as the other post. Not sure what the issue is but it only shows the final data row.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, although it's not elegant and has hardcoded values, but it's a starting point!
It's in MS SQL but has nothing too unusual dialect-wise.
You can play with it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4875/9

```
SELECT
  (SELECT RECORDS_RECORDVALUE FROM PROJECT_RECORDS pr2
   WHERE pr2.RECORDS_LISTCOLUMNID=1
     AND pr1.RECORDS_ROWID=pr2.RECORDS_ROWID
  ) AS col1,
  (SELECT RECORDS_RECORDVALUE FROM PROJECT_RECORDS pr2
   WHERE pr2.RECORDS_LISTCOLUMNID=2
     AND pr1.RECORDS_ROWID=pr2.RECORDS_ROWID
  ) AS col2,
  (SELECT RECORDS_RECORDVALUE FROM PROJECT_RECORDS pr2
   WHERE pr2.RECORDS_LISTCOLUMNID=3
     AND pr1.RECORDS_ROWID=pr2.RECORDS_ROWID
  ) AS col3
FROM 
  PROJECT_RECORDS pr1
GROUP BY RECORDS_ROWID
```

Comment: How would you go about echoing the result in PHP?